# Correct approach for making html form element name configurable in vue

Tags: vue.js, config

What is the correct approach for making the text displayed on my elements in my app configurable please?

For example I have an input form with a label that displays the text name, I’d like through config to change that to first name

If I wanted a config file containing all the labels and other elements listed as key value pairs or similar where I could change the displayed text what is the best approach, is it .env or json files or something else?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can maintain a seperate JSON file for all the hard coded literals and then you can use in your project.

Comment: This may be overkill, but you might take a look at [Vue i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) which is used for internationalization and is build on the mechanism you are looking for. You can use a plugin like [i18n Ally for VS Code](https://github.com/lokalise/i18n-ally) to easy translate keys in to labels in a standardized way for one language. It also gives you the opportunity to easily translate your app in other languages if you need that in the future.